# Not sure why the geodesic derivation equation involved second ordinary derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, geodesics

[image]My question is related to this link (18:10)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQZTYt_Pxcc&list=PLJHszsWbB6hpk5h8lSfBkVrpjsqvUGTCx&index=28

Recently I have watched a video about volume derivation.
In this video,the presenter tried to relate the ordinary derivative of the Volume to the Ricci tensor but i get stuck when i try to understand it.

My problem is that I don't understand why $\ddot{S_j}^{\mu_j} $
is equal to $ -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z y^x$
in 18:10

The reason is
$\ddot{S_j}^{\mu_j} $
should not be equal to 
$ -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z y^x$
where $$[\nabla_v\nabla_vS]^{u^j}= -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z y^x $$since they are different things.
The former one is just second ordinary derivative and the latter one is the full-form second covariant derivative.

I cannot see why it is not second ordinary derivative since volume itself a scalar.
If you take derivative of the volume with ordinary derivative, then the logic should follow in a similar manner and the second derivative of the vector component 
(part of the decomposition because of product rule) should be the ordinary type derivative.

I would now give an example why they are not equal.

Given a 2D-Volume(area) which is spanned by vector $\vec{A} $ and $\vec{B}$, we can take the derivative:

The volume is $ V=\epsilon_{kj} A^kB^j$.
If you take the ordinary derivative of the volume $$\dfrac {dV} {d\lambda}=\epsilon_{jk} [\dfrac{dB^j}{d\lambda}]A^k+\epsilon_{jk} [\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}]B^j$$

and this implies you will take the ordinary derivative of [$A^k$](as a result of product rule) which is $$\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda} $$
however this is just part of the $\nabla_vA$:

$$[∇_vA]^k=\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}[1.]+v^j\Gamma^{k}_{ij}[2]=v^j\dfrac{dA^k}{dx^j} + v^j\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$$

where $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$ is the connection factor that is missed out and $ v^j \dfrac{d}{dx^j}$ is equal to $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$.

It is shown that the ordinary derivative of $A^i$ is just [1.] and [2] is neglected.
[1.] is just the ordinary derivative part of the volume derivation
[2] is the whole derivative which includes connection factor
it is clear that [1.] is not equal to [2].
Therefore$[∇vA]^k$ is not equal to $\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}$.
Follow the similar line of reasoning,i think  $\ddot{S_j}^{\mu_j}=\dfrac{d^2(s^{\mu_j})}{d\lambda^2}$ should not be equal to$[\nabla_v\nabla_vS]^{u^j}$, I am not sure why they are equal

$$\ddot{S_j}^{\mu_j}= \dfrac{d^2(s^{u_j})}{d\lambda^2}\overset{?}{=}[∇v∇vS]^{uj}= R^{u_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z y^x$$

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, they pulled out the volume form by saying that it has a zero covariant derivative. To really make that statement true, you will need $\dfrac{d}{d\lambda}$ to mean $\nabla_{\vec v}=v^i\nabla_{\vec e_i}$. With that change, the remaining derivation will go through nicely. I haven't watched the previous videos, maybe they have adopted such a convention (there are notation styles that use $\dfrac{D}{D\lambda}$ to mean a covariant derivative along a geodesic) or maybe they have made a mistake.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102257/discussion-on-answer-by-poon-levi-not-sure-why-the-geodesic-derivation-equation).